# ggplot2 customized theme: axis title direction issue

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have problem with my customized ggplot2 theme.
Within the theme I customized so that all text will have angle=0, this is a required option when describing the theme. But then by y-axis label is also directed horizontally, whereas I would like to have it at angle=90 because it doesn't fit in the plot.
My code for the custom theme is:

```
windowsFonts(Courier=windowsFont("Courier"))
my_theme<-function (base_size = 12, base_family = "")
{

    theme(text = element_text(size = base_size, family = "Courier", face
                              = "plain",
                              colour = "black", hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5,
                              angle = 0, lineheight = 0.9),
          axis.text  = element_text(size = rel(0.8)),
          axis.ticks = element_line(colour = "black"),
          axis.title.y = element_text(vjust=0.1,angle=90),
          legend.key = element_rect(colour = "grey80"),
          plot.title = element_text(size = rel(2), colour = "blue",face="bold"),
          legend.title = element_text(size = rel(1), colour = "blue"),
          panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white",colour = NA),
          panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, colour = "grey50"),
          panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey50", size = 0.33,linetype="dashed"),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
          strip.background = element_rect(fill = "grey80", colour = "grey50"),
          strip.background = element_rect(fill = "grey80", colour = "grey50"))
}
```

Here I add axis.title.y=element_text(vjust=0.1,angle=90), but when I draw the plot is still at angle=0. Then I added it manually again:

```
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=variable))
p + geom_histogram()+ 
   labs(title = "Plot title",x = "X title", y="Y title")+
   my_theme()+theme(axis.title.y=element_text(angle=90))
```

But still no luck. When I draw the plot without my theme everything is ok, so I guess it's the "angle" option at text=element_text(...) that fixing the angle for any text in the plot. 
Any options how I can make y-axis title rotate while using my theme? Any suggestions is highly appreciated :)

UPD: example using diamonds db from ggplot2 package: 
Head of the dataset:

```
   carat price color clarity
1   0.23   326     E     SI2
2   0.21   326     E     SI1
3   0.23   327     E     VS1
4   0.29   334     I     VS2
5   0.31   335     J     SI2
6   0.24   336     J    VVS2
7   0.24   336     I    VVS1
8   0.26   337     H     SI1
9   0.22   337     E     VS2
10  0.23   338     H     VS1
```

As it seen, the plot doesn't show complete title as it cropped in the leftside

```
data(diamonds)
p <- ggplot(data=diamonds, aes(x=clarity, y=price, fill=clarity)) 
p+geom_bar(width=.7, stat="identity") + 
+     guides(fill=FALSE)+my_theme()+theme(
+         axis.title.y=element_text(angle=90))+
+     xlab("X title")+ylab("Y title")+
+     ggtitle("The big title")
```

[image]

Comment: Can you make your problem reproducible? We don't have `data`. Or at least show us the final figure.

Comment: It doesn't really matter on data, I have many data.frames and everytime data is plotted like that. When I don't add +my_theme() everything is ok though. But I can't manually state all style options in every ggplot procedure, I call it hundreds of time and that's why made customized sample theme. But apparently it ruins my y-axis title

Comment: I agree, but if we have some data handy, we can play with it with little or no effort. Some people are constrained with time and may not be able to make their own example to try out their solutions and might just skip the question.

Comment: Thank for your note! Updated with example from the ggplot2 package

Comment: Courier is not a True Type font. If I run your code, but substitute Courier with Century Gothic (which is True Type), it works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Didn't know of that issue.
Though stating just TT Century Gothic results warnings that such font is not found in windows. But I've solution for the Courier, can use R's standard "mono", which is mapped to "TT Courier New". Thanks again!